# Congrats to new Moderators!

Tags: discussion, moderators

OK, now that Pearsonartphoto has graciously answered my last question, we know that Moderator elections finised 5 hours ago, and Pearsonartphoto, Gilles and Keen (in random order) won!

I'd like to extend official (or rather unofficial) congratulations on the dynamic trio being elected as

<strike>the Timelord Doctors of this insane asylim</strike>

<strike>our new Moderator Overlords</strike>

<strike>the Sheriffs of this wretched hive of scum and villainy</strike>

the moderators of Scifi&Fantasy SE site!

May your decisions be beneficial and unanimously supported and liked!

May you use your powers in a way that is guaranteed not to harm any intelligent living being, through action or inaction!

Comment: By the power of Greyskull, *YOU ARE THE MODERATORS* !

Comment: Also, a 10% turnout? That's worse than America, right?

Comment: The [meta-tag:bug] tag isn't some sort of subtle comment on the outcome, right? ;)

Comment: @TonyMeyer - No, but the fact that elections were announced WAS a bug, no?

Comment: I, for one, welcome our new overlords...

Comment: Congratulations to all three of our new moderators!

Answer (score 14):

More importantly, thanks to @Dampes8n and @Gilles and @MarkRogers (in alphabetical order) for their pro-tem moderation.

Comment: You're Very Welcome.